# SOAP service working fine SOAP UI but parsing WSDL in Java code throws exception

Tags: java, soapui, maven-jaxb2-plugin, cxf-codegen-plugin

SOAP service is working fine in SOAP UI but when I parsed WSDL, either calling direct from URL or from the classpath, two exceptions are thrown. I tried with 2 maven plugins `cxf-codegen-plugin`  and `maven-jaxb2-plugin` but the exceptions are the same. I am curious how the same API works on SOAP UI and not in Java code...

Exceptions throws are:

1. `unbounded prefix 'SOAP-ENV'`
2. `Unexpected <xsd:element> appears`

I listed both plugin configuration below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <strict>false</strict>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>

    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
        <generatePackage>com.soaptesting.product.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
        <schemas>
            <schema>

 <url>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/service.wsdl</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl</wsdl>

                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is the stack trace when compile project with maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
ERROR] URI [/soaptesting/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl] does not provide the scheme part.
[ERROR] Could not resolve the last modification of the URI [/soaptesting/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl] with the scheme [null].
[WARNING] Last modification of the URI [/soaptesting/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl] is not known.
[INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/soaptesting/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl{421,43}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: unbounded prefix 'SOAP-ENV'
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$1.reportError (ParserContext.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError (NGCCRuntimeEx.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError (NGCCRuntimeEx.java:182)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseUName (NGCCRuntimeEx.java:530)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.qname.leaveAttribute (qname.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.consumeAttribute (NGCCRuntime.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.particle.text (particle.java:777)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendText (NGCCRuntime.java:438)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.revertToParentFromText (NGCCHandler.java:185)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.occurs.text (occurs.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendText (NGCCRuntime.java:438)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.occurs.text (occurs.java:284)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendText (NGCCRuntime.java:438)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.occurs.text (occurs.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendText (NGCCRuntime.java:438)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.spawnChildFromText (NGCCHandler.java:138)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.particle.text (particle.java:878)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.processPendingText (NGCCRuntime.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.endElement (NGCCRuntime.java:317)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.endElement (XMLFilterImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner$LocationResolver.endElement (DOMForestScanner.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan (DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan (DOMForestScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL (ModelLoader.java:392)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load (ModelLoader.java:158)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load (ModelLoader.java:117)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.loadModel (XJC23Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/soaptesting/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl{425,30}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected <xsd:element> appears at line 425 column 30
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.unexpectedX (NGCCRuntimeEx.java:632)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.unexpectedEnterElement (NGCCHandler.java:195)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement (complexType.java:655)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement (NGCCRuntime.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.revertToParentFromEnterElement (NGCCHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType_complexContent_body.enterElement (complexType_complexContent_body.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement (NGCCRuntime.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.revertToParentFromEnterElement (NGCCHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.attributeUses.enterElement (attributeUses.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement (NGCCRuntime.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.attributeUses.enterElement (attributeUses.java:182)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement (NGCCRuntime.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.attributeUses.enterElement (attributeUses.java:293)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement (NGCCRuntime.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.spawnChildFromEnterElement (NGCCHandler.java:114)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType_complexContent_body.enterElement (complexType_complexContent_body.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement (NGCCRuntime.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.revertToParentFromEnterElement (NGCCHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.particle.enterElement (particle.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.startElement (NGCCRuntime.java:263)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement (XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner$LocationResolver.startElement (DOMForestScanner.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit (DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan (DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan (DOMForestScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL (ModelLoader.java:392)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load (ModelLoader.java:158)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load (ModelLoader.java:117)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.loadModel (XJC23Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

following is the stack trace by parsing WSDL from wsimport

```
parsing WSDL...


[WARNING] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'responseAwards' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
  line 418 of file:/productssoapapi/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl#types?schema1

[ERROR] unbounded prefix 'SOAP-ENV'
  line 421 of file:/productssoapapi/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl

[ERROR] Unexpected <xsd:element> appears at line 425 column 30
  line 425 of file:/productssoapapi/src/main/resources/wsdl/products.wsdl

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2283)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:183)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
```

Comment: Please share the WSDL and the stacktraces

Comment: I can't share the WSDL it is client property. however, I can share the stack trace

Comment: The `maven-jaxb2-plugin` plugin cannot convert WSDL it is for XSD not WSDL. The CXF one should work, if it doesn't you are missing things in your wsdl/schema location.

Comment: @M.Deinum but the same exceptions come when compiling with CXF

Comment: @M.Deinum i have a requirement to consume SOAP API in springboot application, could you please guide me. I tried several tutorials but failed

Comment: @M.Deinum I tired another WSDL downloaded from the internet is working fine with maven-jaxb2-plugin

Comment: Looks like your wsdl is not properly formatted. What do you get when you run wsimport products.wsdl on the command line?

Comment: @sechanakira I didn't run wsimport even I don't know about it. I just compile through  maven command

Comment: Try running wsimport to see if the wsdl is valid. Open a terminal window and run "wsimport path_or_url_to_wsdl". See if the wsdl can be parsed.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE.

Comment: @sechanakira I tried with wsimport and parsing has been failed. 
errors :

[WARNING] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'responseAwards' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
[ERROR] unbounded prefix 'SOAP-ENV'
[ERROR] Unexpected <xsd:element> appears at line 425 column 30

Comment: @sechanakira I am curious if this WSDL is not formatted than why SOAP UI doesn't give an error. however, service is running fine on SOAP UI

Comment: Definitely, the wsdl is broken. I don't know why or how it worked in SOAP-UI. The frameworks you are using use wsimport internally so your build will break.